# DateTime.Today giving different answers on two different servers

Tags: c#, .net, server-side, windows-server

im getting a really weird problem.
i have two servers with the same time zones and the same dates and time but for some reason im getting on one of the servers the date of yesterday when using DateTime.Today.

any idea why this could happen? i checked the time zones...

thanks!

Comment: if you want a time you can compare between servers, use [`DateTime.UTCNow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Check TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone value on both servers. https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.timezone.currenttimezone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: maybe the actual day is set a day back on one of them ?

Comment: have you checked daylight savings option?